# How to check if curl was successful and print a message?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, curl, terminal

I am trying to do a CURL with an IF Else condition. On success of the call Print a successful message or else Print the call failed.

My Sample Curl would look like:

```
curl 'https://xxxx:1234xxxx@abc.dfghj.com/xl_template.get_web_query?id=1035066' > HTML_Output.html
```

I want to do the same thing using Shell.

Using JavaScript:

```
if(res.status === 200){console.log("Yes!! The request was successful")}
else {console.log("CURL Failed")}
```

Also, I see the CURL percentage, but I do not know, how to check the percentage of CURL. Please help.

CURL output
[image: CURL output]

Comment: Use `curl --fail` and compare the return code to 22 which indicates a failure

Comment: Thanks @dawg ! Just passing `--fail` to curl works. It fails whenever curl command fails.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the `-w` (`--write-out`) option of curl to print the HTTP code:

```
curl -s -w '%{http_code}\n' 'https://xxxx:1234xxxx@abc.dfghj.com/xl_template.get_web_query?id=1035066'
```

It will show the HTTP code the site returns.

Also `curl` provides a whole bunch of exit codes for various scenarios, check `man curl`.

Comment: HTTP code keep printed as `204` even for failures, is it normal ?

Comment: @alper That's what the URL you requested sent as status code in response, nothing to do with `curl` actually.

Answer (score 8):

One way of achieving this like,

```
HTTPS_URL="https://xxxx:1234xxxx@abc.dfghj.com/xl_template.get_web_query?id=1035066"
CURL_CMD="curl -w httpcode=%{http_code}"

# -m, --max-time <seconds> FOR curl operation
CURL_MAX_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT="-m 100"

# perform curl operation
CURL_RETURN_CODE=0
CURL_OUTPUT=`${CURL_CMD} ${CURL_MAX_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT} ${HTTPS_URL} 2> /dev/null` || CURL_RETURN_CODE=$?
if [ ${CURL_RETURN_CODE} -ne 0 ]; then  
    echo "Curl connection failed with return code - ${CURL_RETURN_CODE}"
else
    echo "Curl connection success"
    # Check http code for curl operation/response in  CURL_OUTPUT
    httpCode=$(echo "${CURL_OUTPUT}" | sed -e 's/.*\httpcode=//')
    if [ ${httpCode} -ne 200 ]; then
        echo "Curl operation/command failed due to server return code - ${httpCode}"
    fi
fi
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I want to save the file to html, how to I do this in the above code?                                               curl "https://xxxx:1234xxxx@abc.dfghj.com/xl_template.get_web_query?id=1035066" > Html_Output.html     and     also "-m 100" is taking much to see something printing on terminal. When I reduce the time between 10 to 20 , I see a Connection Failed message

Answer (score 6):

Like most programs, `curl` returns a non-zero exit status if it gets an error, so you can test it with `if`.

```
if curl 'https://xxxx:1234xxxx@abc.dfghj.com/xl_template.get_web_query?id=1035066' > HTML_Output
then echo "Request was successful"
else echo "CURL Failed"
fi
```

I don't know of a way to find out the percentage if the download fails in the middle.

Comment: It will return success for non-200 codes too. See https://superuser.com/questions/272265/getting-curl-to-output-http-status-code

Comment: That's because some successful requests have non-200 codes. A redirect is considered successful, but it returns a 3xx code.